# yfinance no longer provides Symbol for stockinfo?

Tags: python, yfinance

As of this post, sec has it in a "hidden" file https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt.
They may remove but it has over 12K maps right now.

Why is cusip/ticker mapping such a big secret?

If you use sec data, they often provide cusips but no ticker. Also cusips reported are often inconsistent with "official" cusips for the ticker (like NPORT-P).

Can this be incorporated into yfinance?

Comment: "*Can this be incorporated into yfinance??*" seems like a question to the yfinance maintainers, not for StackOverflow: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues